# how to reindex the 'multi - groupbyed' dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains 4 columns, the first 3 columns are numerical variables which indicate the feature of the variable at the last column, and the last column are strings.

I want to merge the last string column by the previous 3 columns through the groupby function. Then it works(I mean the string which shares the same feature logged by the first three columns had been merged successfully)

Previously the length of the dataframe was 1200, and the length of the merged dataframe is 1100. I found the later df is multindexed. Which only contain 2 columns.(hierarchical index ) Thus I tried the reindex method by a generated ascending numerical list. Sadly I failed.

```
df1.columns
*[Out]Index(['time', 'column','author', 'text'], dtype='object')
series = df1.groupby(['time', 'column','author'])
['body_text'].sum()#merge the last column by the first 3 columns
dfx = series.to_frame()# get the new df
dfx.columns
*[Out]Index(['author', 'text'], dtype='object')
len(dfx)
*[Out]1100
indexs = list(range(1100))
dfx.reindex(index = indexs)
*[Out]Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Comment: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reindex` here is not necessary, better is use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or add parameter `as_index=False` to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
 dfx = df1.groupby(['time', 'column','author'])['body_text'].sum().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
 dfx = df1.groupby(['time', 'column','author'], as_index=False)['body_text'].sum()
```